# Delphi FMX RAD Studio Tokyo 10.2 TDateEdit Access violation on picker select

Tags: delphi, datepicker, firemonkey, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Since Version Tokyo I get an access violation, if I select a date from a TDateEdit- Picker...while closing the picker, but only in some applications. RAD Studio Berlin was working fine before.
The components are created programmatically :

```
     tc := TDateEdit.Create(nil);
     tc.Parent := layout;
     tc.ShowCheckBox := true;
     tc.ischecked := false;
     tc.ShowClearButton := true;
     tc.WeekNumbers := true;
```

In the working apps I'm able to debug FMX.DateTimeCtrls, in the error apps breakpoints are disabled in this unit.
The exception raised is in class $C0000005.

Any ideas for a reason....

Comment: it seems TDateEdit is created from another unit..

Comment: found the reason now, but still looking for a solution,

Comment: the error only happens, if a stylebook is loaded and assigned the mainform, for example with transparent.style, if the stylebook is assigned the access violation happens, if not...all is fine, this error was comming up with 10.2 version

Comment: Seems like an issue that has already been reported on Quality portal: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-17197